# Inclusion of "what is your goal"

Tags: discussion

Something that occurs a surprising amount in posts of late is that users are asking questions about improving the way they exercise but are not outlining what their fitness goals are. While outlining goals may not be essential for every user question, is it worth adding to our "help" page or elsewhere that if a questions is about personal fitness that the askers goals should be clearly defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our Help Center in the "Asking" section:

> If you intend on asking about a particular routine or exercise for yourself, please be sure to tell everyone your training goals. The amount of detail you can provide will result in improved answers.

The trouble is that people hardly ever read the help section before asking their first questions.

Comment: Well, that answers that.